# Template PDF Invoice

Tags: invoice, sales, pdf

I've been trying to change some texts in the invoice PDF create at order confirmation, I need to change the text : Order #xxxxxxxx.
Where can I change this ?

I've tried in :

```
app/design/frontend/base/template/sales/order/print.phtml
app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/sales/order/print.phtml
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
```

Nothing worked.

I can't find where this PDF is created, I really need some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` class from a module. Specifically the `insertOrder` method located in the parent `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract` class.

It's a pretty big method to overwrite, specially for something cosmetic. Optionally see if you can change the `Order #` string in the `app/locale/[language]/Mage_Sales.csv` to fit your needs.

But, if you do want to rewrite the new class would look something like this

```
class MageSE_Rewritepdf_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
{

    /**
     * Insert order to pdf page
     *
     * @param Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $obj
     * @param bool $putOrderId
     */
    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        if ($obj instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
            $shipment = null;
            $order = $obj;
        } elseif ($obj instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment) {
            $shipment = $obj;
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        }

        $this->y = $this->y ? $this->y : 815;
        $top = $this->y;

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.45));
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->setDocHeaderCoordinates(array(25, $top, 570, $top - 55));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);

        if ($putOrderId) {
            /**
             * THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT TO CHANGE
             */
            $page->drawText(
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, ($top -= 30), 'UTF-8'
            );
        }

        [...]
        // and the rest of the method
    }
}
```

and the modules `config.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageSE_Rewritepdf>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MageSE_Rewritepdf>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_invoice>MageSE_Rewritepdf_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PDF's are not generated via templates.
You should look in the `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Order/Pdf` folder.  You should get an idea on which class serves each PDF by their names.

Answer (score 0):

Ok As far as I can see I can edit the PDF here :

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/sales/order/print.phtml
```

But I have a module who change this default template, if I desactivate the module it works fine.

I'm gonna look into this module deeper but I think this is another problem.

EDIT : The module is Aitoc Checkout Fields Manager. In fact it create a copy of this file in `var/ait_patch` and that template is used.